# PHP Update Error and Laravel Installation global on Mac OS X

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am getting back to working with Laravel after a few weeks. I was having some trouble with it so I reinstalled it with the directions from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3).

First, I ran  `composer global "require laravel/installer"`.
It changed my directory to local directory: `Changed current directory to /Users/Mark/.composer`.

I ran `laravel new app`:

`Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=5.6.4 but your PHP version (5.5.27) does not satisfy that requirement.`

I tried to run `composer update` but it wouldn't run either. PHP has only 5.6.2 available, not 5.6.4. I think it might be because of the bash profile, but not sure if that is it or how to do that.

Please let me know how to setup up Laravel globally and update PHP for the proper set up of my machine.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: updated in title - Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

I was following the instructions from the PHP documentation when I hit this wall. I searched from Homebrew installation of PHP. As per their [documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php) I then updated it with:

```
 $ brew update
 $ brew upgrade

 Installation

 Setup the homebrew/dupes tap which has dependencies we need:

 $ brew tap homebrew/dupes

Setup the homebrew/versions tap which has dependencies we need:

$ brew tap homebrew/versions

Then, run the following in your command-line:

$ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php

$ brew install php70
```